# Hadoop file system statistics ( FileSystem.Statistics )

Tags: java, hadoop

It seems as though the documentation on hadoop `filesystem.statistics` class is somewhat lacking.

What is meant by "bytes read" and "bytes written" and how are the counters implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

> What is meant by "bytes read" and "bytes written"

According to the [Hadoop : The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449311520)

**Filesystem bytes read** - The number of bytes read by each filesystem by map and reduce tasks. There is a counter for each filesystem: Filesystem may be Local, HDFS, S3, KFS, etc.

**Filesystem bytes written** - The number of bytes written by each filesystem by map and reduce tasks.

> how are the counters implemented ?

Check these tutorials ([1](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/07/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-3-counters-in-action/), [2](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#metrics), [3](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/search/label/counters)) on how counters are implemented.

Comment: this is a helpful answer ...... but its not clear the link between the definition, and the implementation ... in any case, ill take a further look into your tutorials and see if the details are therin.

Comment: It's not clear what's not clear to you :) Go through the tutorials and then through the Hadoop code to understand in more details.